# How to determine $\text{max } |z^n + a|$ for $|z| \leq 1$, $a \in \mathbb{C}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ and $a \in \mathbb{C}$, determine $\text{max } |z^n + a|$ for $|z| \leq 1$.

I do not understand the question, what is it exactly that I need to determine? And how do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

$$F=|z^n+a| \le |z^n| + |a| \le 1+|a|$$

Answer (score 0):

You may understand the problem geometrically. Note that $|z| \le 1$ represents a unit circle in the complex plane. Moreover, let $w=z^n$ and $|w|= |z^n| =|z|^n\le 1$, which also represents a unit circle centered at origin.

Then, $|z^n+a| = |w+a|$ represents the distance between the points $w$ in the unit circle and the point $-a$ in the complex plane. The furthest point of the circle away from the point $-a$ is the distance of $-a$ to origin $|a|$ plus the radius 1.

Thus, $\max(|w+a|) = |a|+1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a=0$ the answer is obviously $1$ and any $|z|=1$ will get it.

If $a \ne 0, a=re^{it}, -\pi < t \le \pi$, so pick $z=e^{\frac{it}{n}}$, then $|z^n+a|=|(1+r)e^{it}|=1+r=1+|a|$, while the triangle inequality shows that indeed $|z^n+a| \le 1+|a|$, so we attain the maximum at that $z$ and obviously by periodicity we can rotate it by any root of unity of order $n$